# Javascript billing function

Tags: javascript

this is a question i cam across recently. 
there is a from in the webpage and user can input values for "unit price" and "quantity". when user hits the "find amount" button, the total is displayed in the text field "amount". function "calAmount" calculates the total amount based on the equation : amount = unitprice*quantity.
But i have a problem in writing this "calAmount" function. can someone help me?

```
<form name = "order" method = "POST">
        <p>Unit price :
        <input type = "text" name = "unitPrice" maxlength = "9" /></p>
        <p>Quantity &nbsp: 
        <input type = "text" name = "quantity" maxlength = "5"/></p>
        <p>Amount: &nbsp:
        <input type = "text" name = "amount" maxlength = "12"></p>
        <input name = "btnCal" type = "button" id = "btnCal" value = "Find amount" onclick="calAmount()"/>
        <br/><br/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with `name` attribute to select the element.
- Access `value` property of the element.
- Use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert `value` to `Number`

```js
function calAmount() {
  var unitPrice = document.querySelector('[name="unitPrice"]');
  var quantity = document.querySelector('[name="quantity"]');
  var amount = document.querySelector('[name="amount"]');
  amount.value = Number(unitPrice.value) * Number(quantity.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="order" method="POST">
  <p>Unit price :
    <input type="text" name="unitPrice" maxlength="9" />
  </p>
  <p>Quantity &nbsp:
    <input type="text" name="quantity" maxlength="5" />
  </p>
  <p>Amount: &nbsp:
    <input type="text" name="amount" maxlength="12">
  </p>
  <input name="btnCal" type="button" id="btnCal" value="Find amount" onclick="calAmount()" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks man. it works like a charm. where i got stuck was that when i began to write the calAmount() function, there were no "id" s in the form elements. so i got confused. but now with your correct code, i have figured that out. once again, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `calAmount()` function should be like this

```js
function calAmount() {
  var unitPrice = document.getElementById('unitPrice').value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;

  document.getElementById('amount').value = unitPrice * quantity;
}
```

```html
<form name="order" method="POST">
  <p>Unit price :
    <input type="text" name="unitPrice" id="unitPrice" maxlength="9" />
  </p>
  <p>Quantity &nbsp:
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" maxlength="5" />
  </p>
  <p>Amount: &nbsp:
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" maxlength="12">
  </p>
  <input name="btnCal" type="button" id="btnCal" value="Find amount" onclick="calAmount()" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
</form>
```